# Имеют ли указатели на функции свое собственное соглашение о вызоывах?

Tags: c++, linux, c, c++17, совместимость

Не могу найти соглашение о вызовах применяемое указателем на функцию. Меня интересует не будет ли конфликта при передаче коллбека из с++ кода в с код.

К примеру у меня есть шаблонная функция, и я хочу передать указатель на ее имплементированную форму fn = func

```
template<typename T>
void func() {
}
```

Не вызовет ли это конфликтов?

Comment: Соглашения те же самые, но если имплементирванная форма является методом класса, то сишный код должен передать первым аргументом указатель на объект данного класса (this в терминах С++)

Comment: А кто такие вызоывы?

Comment: конфликтов не будет точно если вы создадите extern C функцию, которая вызывает реализацию вашего шаблона и передадите указатель на эту новую функцию.